# Calcul of the mean from diagonals of a matrix + incrementation

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

I've this kind of matrix.

I'm really sorry but I don't have a reproducible example.

Table 1 :

```
      [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6][,7][,8][,9][,10]
[1,]    3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[2,]    4   2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[3,]    4   1   7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[4,]    4   1   2   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[5,]    5   2   0   0   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[6,]    2   0   3   3   5   9   NA  NA  NA  NA
[7,]    6   2   0   0   3   4   2   NA  NA  NA
[8,]    12  6   4   3   1   0   2   6   NA  NA
[9,]    16  11  7   6   5   3   4   0   3   NA
[10,]   19  15  13  9   7   6   6   3   3   5
```

and I would like to create another one like this :
Reconstruct column from diagonal.

Table 2:

```
      [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6][,7][,8][,9]
[1,]    3   4   4   5   2   6   12  16  19
[2,]    2   1   1   0   2   6   11  15  NA
[3,]    7   2   0   0   4   7   13  NA  NA
[4,]    3   0   3   3   6   9   NA  NA  NA
[5,]    5   5   3   5   7   NA  NA  NA  NA
[6,]    9   4   0   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[7,]    2   2   4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[8,]    6   0   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[9,]    3   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
[10,]   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA



Table 2[,1]= Table 1[1,1];[2,2];[3;3]
Table 2[,2]= Table 1 [2,1];[3,2];[4,3]
Table 2[,3]= Table 1 [3,1];[4,2];[5,3]
```

I tried this code, but without success.

```
Table2=matrix(NA, ncol=10, nrow=10)
for(i in 0:9)
{
  Table2[i+1]=Table1[i+1,i+1]
}
```

Next step, will be to compute a colMean.
All this is for a cross validation to evaluate a sarima.
Here it's just an example, in real data base, i've more than 100 col and 100 rows/

Thanks so much

Comment: I already try to transpose the matrix. but it doesn't work. i need to read the diagonal of the matrix .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
t(apply(t(yr_mat), 1, function(x) c(na.omit(x), rep(NA, sum(is.na(x))))))
```

Taking the transpose of the matrix gets you this far:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
V1     3    4    4    4    5    2    6   12   16    19
V2    NA    2    1    1    2    0    2    6   11    15
V3    NA   NA    7    2    0    3    0    4    7    13
V4    NA   NA   NA    3    0    3    0    3    6     9
V5    NA   NA   NA   NA    5    5    3    1    5     7
V6    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    9    4    0    3     6
V7    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    2    2    4     6
V8    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    6    0     3
V9    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    3     3
V10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     5
```

So what you need is to 'slide over' all the rows, so the values are all the way left with trailing NAs. The function does this by truncating all `NA`s in each row, then adding back as many NAs after the good values.

Finally, you have to transpose all that again so it's oriented the way you want.

The output is:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
V1     3    4    4    4    5    2    6   12   16    19
V2     2    1    1    2    0    2    6   11   15    NA
V3     7    2    0    3    0    4    7   13   NA    NA
V4     3    0    3    0    3    6    9   NA   NA    NA
V5     5    5    3    1    5    7   NA   NA   NA    NA
V6     9    4    0    3    6   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
V7     2    2    4    6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
V8     6    0    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
V9     3    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
V10    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a numeric index ('indx') using the `row` and `col` of 'm1', then `split` the matrix ('m1') by 'indx', convert the 'list' to 'matrix' by `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`.  We get the output as character strings, that can be converted to 'numeric'.

```
library(stringi)
indx <- (row(m1)-col(m1)+1L)*(NA^upper.tri(m1))
matrix(as.numeric(stri_list2matrix(split(m1, indx))), dim(m1))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    3    4    4    4    5    2    6   12   16    19
# [2,]    2    1    1    2    0    2    6   11   15    NA
# [3,]    7    2    0    3    0    4    7   13   NA    NA
# [4,]    3    0    3    0    3    6    9   NA   NA    NA
# [5,]    5    5    3    1    5    7   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [6,]    9    4    0    3    6   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [7,]    2    2    4    6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [8,]    6    0    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [9,]    3    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[10,]    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 19L, NA, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 15L, NA, NA, 7L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
4L, 7L, 13L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 9L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, 4L, 0L, 
3L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 6L, 0L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L), .Dim = c(10L, 10L),
.Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```